# React Native - Logout after 5 minutes with two screens (components)

Tags: reactjs, settimeout, native, logout, panresponder

I have an expo application and I want to implement automatic logout after 5 minutes.

In the first component that is shown when the user logs in I created:

The code below works fine but when I change to the new screen (new component) I can't renew the time to logout.

How I can renew the time on the next screen?

```
componentWillMount() {
  this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => {
      clearTimeout(this.timeout)

      this.setState((state) => {
        if (state.inactive == false) return null
        return {
          inactive: false
        }
      })

      this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
          inactive: true
        })
      }, 300000)

      return false
    }
  })
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  clearTimeout(this.timeout)
}
```

In the  of the screen, I had put `{... this._panResponder.panHandlers}`.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the common component and inherits all the components from the common one. And you should implement the above code in common components.

Comment: I had tried to do it, I had create a component and put the code inside to teste.


function LogoutAfterTime(TimeToLogout) {
    console.warn('its works')

    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        Alert.alert('I am appearing...','After 5 second!')
        }, TimeToLogout);
}

but when I call the component inside the screen 1 its works, but when I call the component again for the screen 2 it isn't works. The time continue the same of the first screen

Comment: @Ce8 Could you share the full source code, please? so that I can check on my side, there could be other problems related to that issue.

Comment: I can't do it because I have others business code inside.
My problem is simple. I want to make a logout after 5 minutes, but I have to screens in my app and when the user change the screen I can renew the time. 
I Follow this example: https://codedaily.io/tutorials/140/How-to-Detect-Touch-Inactivity-with-a-PanResponder-in-React-Native